# What type of expression is this?

Tags: c#

I've seen it sometimes, but can't remember where.

It goes something like:

```
bool Bool = true;
string Result = (Bool ? true : return "It was true");
```

Not sure if I'm doing it right, but what's this expression type called and how is it done?

Comment: How did you manage to compile this stuff?

Comment: `bool someCondition = true; string result = someCondition ? "The condition is true" : "The condition is false";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is (almost) the [C# Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Note that your code should read:

```
string result = Bool ? "It was true" : "It was false";
```

Effectively, the first section after the ? is what occurs when the statement (`Bool`) is true, the second (after the `:`) is what you get when it's false.

This is similar in effect to:

```
string result;
if (Bool)
    result = "It was true";
else
    result = "It was false";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also sometimes referred to as the [Ternary Operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.90).aspx)

"Ternary" meaning 3, since this operator takes 3 parameters.

Comment: Nice - old school VS 2008 documentation! :-)